# Zend_Dojo_Form in tabs creates ID conflicts

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, dojo

I have a dojo layout that creates a sidebar on the left with a list of pages and a center area which is a tab container.

When a user double clicks a page in the sidebar, it creates a new closable tab in the center with a form to edit that page (the form is loaded via the href attribute on the ContentPanes, it's a standard Zend Framework request). However, if I open two or more pages, it creates all the elements and form controls with the same dijit IDs which creates conflicts. (This is expected I guess)

Aside from manually appending the current page ID to every element/dijit on the tab contents, does anyone know of a cleaner way for me to do this? Will this be an issue with the form element name attributes still being the same?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the other approach is to not put id's on any of your widgets.